# Is there a way to automate changing the hue of many layers with a different value per layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, automation, actions

Let's say I have 100 photos in a folder. On the first one, I would like to change the `Hue` to `-180`, and save it. On the second one, I would like to change the `Hue` to `-170`. On the third one, I would like to change the `Hue` to `-160`, and so on.

Is there a way to batch process with a different value each time?

Comment: By definition, it wouldn't really be "batch" processing if there's a variation each time.

Answer (score 9):

I'd probably use [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

There is a feature available to modify the hue, but it's percentage based instead of degrees.

> ### [Hue Modulation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate_hue)
>
> Rotates the colors of the image, in a cyclic manner. To achieve this the Hue value given produces a 'modulus addition', rather than a multiplication.
>   However be warned that the hue is rotated using a percentage, and not by an angle.
>
> ```
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,0      mod_hue_0.gif
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,33.3   mod_hue_33.gif
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,66.6   mod_hue_66.gif
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,100    mod_hue_100.gif
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,133.3  mod_hue_133.gif
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,166.6  mod_hue_166.gif
> convert rose:   -modulate 100,100,200    mod_hue_200.gif
> ```
>
> #### Result:
>
> [image: hue modulation: 0] [image: hue modulation: 33.3] [image: hue modulation: 66.6] [image: hue modulation: 100] [image: hue modulation: 133.3] [image: hue modulation: 166.6] [image: hue modulation: 200]

Most of the heavy lifting is done for you in that example, you would just need to create a script that indexes all the files in a directory and applies a sequential value given to the modulate argument.

Comment: +1 for imageMagick. Fiddly to get going, but extraordinarily powerful.

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished with PS scripting. As it is a pretty unique request, you might have trouble finding an existing script that does that. You'd probably either have to code it up yourself or hire someone who can do it for you.

Comment: Already provided ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a script that will do just that. Just save it as something like `changeHuePerLayer.jsx` and drag and drop it on top the Photoshop dock icon on the Mac. On Windows I think you need to open it from the menu (not sure where).

```
#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();

var
    LOWER_HUE_LIMIT = -180,
    UPPER_HUE_LIMIT = 180;
var
    hueValue = LOWER_HUE_LIMIT,
    hueIncrementor = 10,
    currentDoc = app.activeDocument;


for ( var i = 0; i < currentDoc.layers.length; i++ ) {
    currentDoc.activeLayer = currentDoc.layers[i];
    hueValue = hueValue < UPPER_HUE_LIMIT ? hueValue + hueIncrementor : LOWER_HUE_LIMIT;
    applyHsl( hueValue, 0, 0 );
}


/**
 *
 * @param {number} hue
 * @param {number} saturation
 * @param {number} lightness
 */
function applyHsl( hue, saturation, lightness ) {
    var HUE_SAT_ADJUSTMENT_V2_SYM  = 'Hst2';
    var COLORIZE_SYM               = 'Clrz';
    var ADJUSTMENT_SYM             = 'Adjs';
    var HUE_SYM                    = 'H   ';
    var SATURATION_SYM             = 'Strt';
    var LIGHTNESS_SYM              = 'Lght';
    var HUE_SATURATION_SYM         = 'HStr';

    var colorizeDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
    var hueSatDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
    var hueSatAdjustmentList = new ActionList();

    colorizeDescriptor.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID( COLORIZE_SYM ), false );

    hueSatDescriptor.putInteger( charIDToTypeID( HUE_SYM ), hue );
    hueSatDescriptor.putInteger( charIDToTypeID( SATURATION_SYM ), saturation );
    hueSatDescriptor.putInteger( charIDToTypeID( LIGHTNESS_SYM ), lightness );

    hueSatAdjustmentList.putObject( charIDToTypeID( HUE_SAT_ADJUSTMENT_V2_SYM ), hueSatDescriptor );
    colorizeDescriptor.putList( charIDToTypeID( ADJUSTMENT_SYM ), hueSatAdjustmentList );

    executeAction(
        charIDToTypeID( HUE_SATURATION_SYM ),
        colorizeDescriptor,
        DialogModes.NO
    );
}
```